# TensorFlow with c++, codeblocks

Tags: c++, tensorflow, motion-detection

I'm working with c++ for motion recognition, is it possible to use tensorFlow with "codeblocks"?. I have found tutorial with visual studio only. Is there any other library for implementing the Time Delay Neural Network (TDNN). Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please consider adding links, code and a more thorough explanation of what the question is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codeblocks is an editor for c++ programs. Tensorflow is most usable as python code. As editor, I would NOT recommend codeblocks.

As for any other library for the TDNN: if you are searching for another library that works with neural networks: openNN is a library that works with C++ http://www.opennn.net/.

Hope this helps!

Comment: tensorflow has python, c++ and java api